# How to get a filtered set of values from JSON.stringify

Tags: json

Currently, I am getting both boolean values in "ids". How can I filter so that I get only true values.

fetchValue( event ) {

```
    console.log( 'Value from Child LWC is ' + event.detail );
    this.strOutput = event.detail;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.strOutput))
    var ids = this.strOutput.todolist.map(x => x.isCompleted)
    console.log(ids)
    
    console.log('What'+this.temp)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

May be 'x.isCompleted' is a string and not a boolean. Did you check this?

If it is a string then,

```
var ids = this.strOutput.todolist.map(x => x.isCompleted === 'true');
```

might work.

Comment: My data looks something like this. I want to filter the array to show only those which has isCompleted == true {title: "", todolist: Array(2), iconname: "utility:add"}
iconname: "utility:add"
title: ""
todolist: Array(2)
0: {title: "bh", id: 77, isCompleted: false}
1: {title: "bj", id: 89, isCompleted: true}